# Uniform Initializing vector of strings causes address sanitizer error

Tags: c++, string, c++11, vector, address-sanitizer

Previously I had code that would create a vector of strings and add one element via:

```
std::vector<std::string> attempt_one;
attempt_one.emplace_back( "Hello, world!" );
```

This code compiles and works as expect. If I attempt to instead create the vector of strings as

```
std::vector<std::string> attempt_two{ "Hello, world!" };
```

the code compiles fine, but when compiled with the address sanitizer enabled, the code fails at run time with the error:

```
Sanitizer CHECK failed: /...long_path.../asan_mapping.h:179 ((AddrIsInMem(p))) != (0) (0, 0)
```

What is the bug in my second attempt at creating the vector that is causing this error? For reference this is Clang 3.7 with the -std=c++11 and address sanitizer enabled.

Comment: Did you use libc++ or stdlibc++? The latter requires some work to function with the clang sanitizers afaik.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: Yes, you need to build the library with the sanitizers, too.

Comment: That was the problem, great catch, thank you.